# Error when trying to get a component by union type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an object where the keys are the types of windows I want to call, and the values are the components of the windows themselves. I get the type of window I want to call and get it from the object, and then I try to pass it props, but TypeScript gives me an error:

```
Type 'IWindow' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  The intersection 'IWindowGameCreate & IWindowGameCreateError' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'IWindowGameCreate' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Code:

```
interface IWindowProps {
  readonly window: IWindow;
  readonly pause: () => void;
  readonly resume: () => void;
}

const windows = {
  [WindowType.GAME_CREATE]: GameCreateWindow,
  [WindowType.GAME_CREATE_ERROR]: GameCreateWindowError,
};

function Window({ window, pause, resume }: IWindowProps) {
  const Win = useMemo(() => windows[window.type], [window.type]);

  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={() => pause()} onMouseLeave={() => resume()}>
      <Win window={window} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Types:

```
interface IWindowBase {
  readonly id: string;
}

export enum WindowType {
  GAME_CREATE,
  GAME_CREATE_ERROR,
}

export interface IWindowGameCreate extends IWindowBase {
  readonly type: WindowType.GAME_CREATE;
  readonly gameId: number;
}

export interface IWindowGameCreateError extends IWindowBase {
  readonly type: WindowType.GAME_CREATE_ERROR;
  readonly gameId: number;
}

export type IWindow = IWindowGameCreate | IWindowGameCreateError;
```

Components:

```
interface IGameCreateWindowProps {
  readonly window: IWindowGameCreate;
}

export function GameCreateWindow({ window }: IGameCreateWindowProps) {
  return <span>{window.gameId}</span>;
}

interface IGameCreateErrorWindowProps {
  readonly window: IWindowGameCreateError;
}

export function GameCreateErrorWindow({ window }: IGameCreateErrorWindowProps) {
  return <span>{window.gameId}</span>;
}
```

Comment: What line produces that error? Your code does not seem to show that error: https://tsplay.dev/Na2O6m

Comment: @AlexWayne fix: https://tsplay.dev/mZ4k4w